# Outlook stops reply in the format of the sent email

Tags: microsoft-outlook

today when I reply to an email, Outlook breaks all the formatting of the original email. The font, text color are all converted to black Arial. How can I fix this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change your default mail formatting when replying to html. If it's set to plain text or even rich text it will break html formatting. Also, if someone emailed you in plain/rich text it will automatically reply in the same.

The following screenshot is from Office '10.

[image]